# Newly added Page not work only redirect to 404 Error Page

Tags: magento2, page, cms-pages

I added a new page in Magento 2 with url newpage but it return with 404 Not Found eror.

I compared it to a working page and the setting

Comment: Which magento version you are using ? and how you set new page ?

Comment: Im using the newest Magento 2.1.3 version and simply go to Conent --> Pages --> Add New Page. Add page title,some conent,url key than save it. Also flush cache,reindex,setup:upgrade,cleaning browser history.

I have one store mode enabled so i dont need to set it,but when i go to mydomain.com/newpageurl it shows 404 NOT Found page.

Comment: @Chriss Simply add page  and its content from content->page->add new page . Then leave blank url , key and other options as of now . and check if page is shown on frontend then after edit that page and change url if you wish. Make sure no space in between that

Comment: When i add it to the Home Menu Buttons the whole section disappear

Comment: Share the screenshots or steps how you add that new page on the home menu ?

Comment: Thanks for hepling meanwhile it turned out the problem comes from "single store mode" option.
I wasnt possible to set store view this way and didnt work.

Comment: try to load `newpage.html`

Comment: If anyone still uses **Magento v.2.1.x** and has this issue, use the following https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5008#issuecomment-326201943 to resolve  the 404 "Not Found" pages.

Comment: Adding the row on cms_page_store with page_id and store_id works. Thank you @PaRnanZio Gun.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known but in "Magento 2.1".

"This is only happening in single store mode for me. Disabling single store mode forces you to define the relationship by selecting a view when adding a new page (all store views, default store view, etc). Therefore it updates the cms_page_store table fine."

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5008

Answer (score 0):

Just create a row in the table `cms_page_store` with your `page_id` and your `store_id` (should be 0)